# Jar file not able to identify log4j classes when using from a different project

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j

I have developed a wrapper of log4j for custom logging purpose . My requirement is that the wrapper will be imported as a jar file in another project for further logging purposes. After successfully building the jar when I am going to use the jar in a separate project I am getting the following error .

---

I have tried including the jar both by maven dependency after installing in my local maven repo and also by importing as an external jar . But none of them worked . Any type of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated . Thanks in advance .

---

I am getting an error as follows Exception in thread "main":

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager at com.jcg.logging.WrapperLoggerFactory.<clinit>(WrapperLoggerFactory.java:12
```

Comment: Wrapping log4j?  I wouldn't recommend that.  There are a million logging solutions out there.  A better idea is to pick one and go with it.  That error suggests that the JAR isn't available at run time.  You might have a packaging issue.

Comment: I need some specific information like input and output data for each API , execution time for each method to be printed in the log file . The log file will be used as an input of kibbana  and I am not able to do this much customisation in the log configuration . So I don't think I have any other solution apart from wrapping the log4j logger .

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: As @Robert said, edit the question instead.  I did it for the exception comment (first one is free :-).